# rmarkdown does not render foreign characters correctly

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have created a new RMarkdown document (temp.rmd) in RStudio with this content:

```
---
output: html_document
---

These are foreign characters.

# abcåöäå
```

If I click the 'Knit' button, it renders correctly as below:

[image]

If I run, `rmarkdown::render("temp.rmd")`, it exports an html file like below:

[image]

I have tried 'File > Save with Encoding... > UTF-8'. But, that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any suggestions to fix this?

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

knitr_1.18
rmarkdown_1.8
```

Comment: what is the encoding of the html file produced (meta tag at the beginning of the html file)?. I have tried on my computer and the characters are correctly rendered.

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Try forcing the encoding: `rmarkdown::render("temp.rmd", encoding="UTF-8")`

Comment: Are you sure it is not your browser that assumes the encoding is something other than utf8 ? If I open the html source produced by my computer in Rstudio, the characters also appear correctly (at line 126)

Comment: Oh. I just tried 'File > Save with Encoding... > WINDOWS-1252'. Then ran `rmarkdown::render("temp.rmd")` and it renders correctly. The character meta in the html file still says `<meta charset="utf-8">`. I am not sure what's going on here.